# How to generate a repeating series from an increasing integer

Tags: c#, math

I need a function that will take in input number to int.Max and give me a number between 0 and 12 - so 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 are valid numbers.

I thought about doing it in the following way, but I think there must be a better way?

```
private static int GetNumberBetweenZeroAndTweleve(int inputNumber)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < inputNumber; i++)
    {
        // something elegant to calculate a number
        result++;
        if (result == 12)
            result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example Input => output:

```
1 => 1
2 => 2
3 => 3
4 => 4
5 => 5
6 => 6
7 => 7
8 => 8
9 => 9
10 => 10
11 => 11
12 => 1
13 => 2
14 => 3
```

etc.

Comment: if you need a random number between `0` - `12` then why do you need a _input number to int.Max_?

Comment: How is `inputNumber` related to the expected output?

Comment: I do not understand what is the purpose of `GetNumberBetweenZeroAndTweleve`.

Comment: Are you looking for the [mod operator(%)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)?

Comment: I've given some sample output to help clarify what I want.  The code I gave does this. But I think there must be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want any *loops* (which can be *expensive* in case of big `inputNumber`: `int.MaxValue` is `2147483647`) but

```
 private static int GetNumberBetweenZeroAndTweleve(int inputNumber) {
   return inputNumber <= 0
     ? 1
     : (inputNumber - 1) % 11 + 1;
 }
```

Test:

```
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(1, 14)
  .Select(n => $"{n,2} => {GetNumberBetweenZeroAndTweleve(n),2}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
 1 =>  1
 2 =>  2
 3 =>  3
 4 =>  4
 5 =>  5
 6 =>  6
 7 =>  7
 8 =>  8
 9 =>  9
10 => 10
11 => 11
12 =>  1
13 =>  2
14 =>  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer based on your example:

```
private static int GetNumberBetweenZeroAndTweleve(int inputNumber)
{
    return inputNumber < 12 ? Math.Max(inputNumber, 1) : inputNumber % 12 + 1;
}
```

And without if-else shortcut:

```
private static int GetNumberBetweenZeroAndTweleve(int inputNumber)
{
    if (inputNumber < 12)
        return Math.Max(inputNumber, 1);

    return inputNumber % 12 + 1;
}
```